# MySqlClient: SaveChanges in ASP.NET doesn't update DB table

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq, connector

I'm using MySql database in ASP.NET MVC 4 project with MySqlClient (MySQL Connector .NET ).
In the References are dlls: MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entry, MySql.Web
Selects from MySql database executes successfully, but inserts and updates are doesn't executes. No errors, no exceptions.

code №1:

```
var connectionString = "Server=my_server;Uid=my_login;Pwd=my_password;Old Guids=true;persist security info=True;database=clientest;allow zero datetime=True;convert zero datetime=True";

            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                String commandText = "update testdb.visit set doctor_spec='dentist' where visit_id = 2;";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandText, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

No errors, no exception, but the table hasn't updates

code №2

```
using (var db = new MySqlDBEntities())
{
                var vx = (from v in db.visit where v.visit_id == 1 select v).FirstOrDefault();
                vx.doctor_spec = "dentist";
                db.SaveChanges();
}
```

No errors, no exception, but the table hasn't updates.

What's wrong? Maybe another way for using MySql in ASP.NET MVC projects?

P.S. Sorry for my poor English :(

Answer (score 0):

check connection in web config and find Correctly Data File 
After Do Save Change Successfully any Edited Or New Entity Changes is Update

check this code too
 *** from v in db.visit /* db.visits */ where ***